# How many tenses are there in English?

Tags: tense

I've been searching about this a bit.
Some say there are 12:

> There are three main tenses: past, present, and future. In English,
> each of these tenses can take four main aspects: simple, perfect,
> continuous (also known as progressive), and perfect continuous. The
> perfect aspect is formed using the verb to have, while the continuous
> aspect is formed using the verb to be.

[image]

Some say there are 16:

> 1. Present Simple - I play
> 2. Present Continuous - I am playing
> 3. Present Perfect - I have played
> 4. Present Perfect Continuous - I have been playing
> 5. Past Simple - I played
> 6. Past Continuous - I was playing
> 7. Past Perfect - I had played
> 8. Past Perfect Continuous - I had been playing
> 9. Future Simple - I will play (including "be going to + infinitive" form) I am goint to play
> 10. Future Continuous - I will be playing
> 11. Future Perfect - I will have played
> 12. Future Perfect Continuous - I will have been playing
> 13. Future Simple in the past - I would play (including the "was/were going to + infinitive" form)
> 14. Future Continuous in the past - I would be bathing
> 15. Future Perfect in the past - I would have played
> 16. Future Perfect Continuous in the past - I would have been playing

Some say [there are 18](https://www.freeed.com/articles/3570/how-many-tenses-there-really-are-in-english-and-why-we-should-view-english-grammar-from-a-more-critical-perspective)

> Most mainstream grammar and course books will present you with the following list of verb tenses:
>
> 1- Present Simple (I study English every day.)
>
> 2- Present Continuous (I’m studying English at the moment.)
>
> 3- Present Perfect Simple (I’ve studied English for ages/since a very
> young age.)
>
> 4- Present Perfect Continuous (I’ve been studying a lot of English
> lately.)
>
> 5- Past Simple (I studied English last year.)
>
> 6- Past Continuous (I was studying English when you called me.)
>
> 7- Past Perfect Simple (I had already studied English before I moved
> to Canada.)
>
> 8- Past Perfect Continuous (I had been studying English for many years
> when I decided to become an English teacher.)
>
> 9- Future Simple (I will probably study English at a higher level in
> the future.)
>
> 10- Future Continuous (I’ll be studying English at that time
> tomorrow.)
>
> 11- Future Perfect Simple (At that time next week, I will have studied
> English for at least 10 hours.)
>
> 12- Future Perfect Continuous (By the time I move to Canada, I’ll have
> been studying English for many years.)
>
> 13- “Futurity” (“going to” future for intentions) (I’m going to study
> English this afternoon.)
>
> 14- “Futurity in the past” (I was going to study English today, but I
> had unexpected visitors.)
>
> Some grammar books will also include the so called “Conditional
> tenses” (or Future Past tenses):
>
> 15- Simple conditional (I would study English.)
>
> 16- Continuous conditional (I would be studying English.)
>
> 17- Perfect conditional (I would have studied English.)
>
> 18- Perfect Continuous conditional (I would have been studying English.)
>
> As you can see, there are 12 main “tenses”, plus other 2 ways of
> expressing future intentions, plus other 4 conditional/future-past
> “tenses”.

And some even say there are 24 or 26. It is a little complicated and most grammar books like the ones that I have, `Grammar in Use` and `Grammar for IELTS` do not teach the tenses integrated in one place instead they do teach the tenses based on their application.
So here I want a comprehensive post which can be cited later about tenses in English and time expressions for each as it is learned by a native speaker at school.

Comment: This question has been asked on our sister site English Language & Usage. You might be shocked to learn that  many linguists assert that there are just two tenses in English. The present and the past.

Comment: [How many tenses are there in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91122/how-many-tenses-are-there-in-english)

Comment: See also [Is it true that English has no future tense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429932/is-it-true-that-english-has-no-future-tense/430155#430155)

Comment: Native speakers don't actually learn "tenses" in school - it is part of their native language so they already "know" about tenses.  There are some grammar lessons in English class for native speakers, but these are lessons for children, and so are taught in a way that can be understood by children - and are usually taught by teachers who don't specialise in English. So there is *no standard list of tenses taught in English schools*  As MariLou says, the correct answer is probably "2", other time expressions are formed analytically with helper verbs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no categorical answer. "English verbs are complex and you probably can't count how many forms they have."  Please refer to the [English.se] question for details.

Comment: In very simple terms, you could say that are just two: present and preterite (past). The simple past and perfect are two instances of the preterite tense, the simple past being the primary (inflectional) past tense, the perfect the secondary (analytic) past tense.

Comment: Note that 'progressive' is not a tense but an aspect, and 'conditional' is not a tense either but a type of construction found in conditional adjuncts.

Comment: This chart says "She is listening the music" and "You will mary me" and "They had been being friend"?!?!  Throw this chart in the trash, because it is garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodney Huddleston, the lead author of the award-winning grammar CGEL (*The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language*) puts it like this:

> "I think it is better to say that English has two tense systems: an
> inflectional system contrasting preterite and present, and an
> independent analytic tense system contrasting perfect and non-perfect,
> where non-perfect is not a tense but the absence of perfect tense. The
> perfect tense can combine with preterite and present tense but can
> also occur in clauses without inflectional tense.
>
> On our account preterite and perfect are both instances of the more
> general tense 'past'. Preterite is the primary (inflectional) past
> tense, while perfect is the secondary (analytic) past tense".

I'd go along with that.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: There are only two tenses in English.**

### What is a tense?

In grammar, **tense** is a category that expresses time reference. The main tenses found in many languages include the **past**, **present**, and **future**. Some languages only have two tenses (past & nonpast / future & nonfuture). There are also tenseless languages, like Chinese. English has only two tenses: the **present** and the **past**. Note that **English does not have a future tense**. We don't have a verb conjugation for the future tense. I'm not going to talk about how to express about the future here, if you are confused about it, **tell me in the comment**.

### What about perfect, progressive that sort of thing?

That's not a **tense**, they're **aspects**. In liguistics, aspect is a grammatical category that express how an action, event, or state, denoted by a verb, extends over time.

### Aspects in English

There are four aspects in English:

- [Simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_present)
- [Progressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_continuous)
- [Perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect)
- [Perfect progressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Present_perfect_progressive/continuous)

### Modal verbs

Modal verbs are used to express certain hypothetical conditions, such as advice, capability, or requests. They’re used alongside a main verb to change its meaning slightly. Because they’re auxiliary verbs, they can’t necessarily be used on their own. (A modal verb should only appear alone if it’s clear from context what the main verb is.)

The principal English modal verbs are *[can / could](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Can_and_could)*, *[may / might](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#May_and_might)*, *[shall / should](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Shall_and_should)*, *[will / would](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Will_and_would)*, and *[must](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Must)*. Certain other verbs are sometimes, but not always, classed as modals; these include *ought*, *had better*, and (in certain uses) *dare* and *need*.

### Tense vs Aspect

Tense and aspect are often labelled as the same thing. It’s not uncommon to see the present progressive referred to as ‘the present progressive tense’ or will have + past participle referred to as ‘the future perfect tense’, for example. However, tense and aspect are not the same thing.

### Don't forget about voice

Because we also have active voice and passive voice in English, which refer to the subject and the object are assigned to the verb.

- Active: I will always remember my first trip abroad.
- Passive: My first trip abroad will always be remembered by me.

These have nothing to do with tense, but they are still part of the verbal paradigm.

### Conclusion

***English verbs are complex and you probably can't count how many forms they have.***

### Attributions

[What is a tense?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_tense) by Wikipedia
[What about perfect, progressive that sort of thing?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) by Wikipedia
[Aspects in English](https://www.lawlessenglish.com/learn-english/grammar/tense-aspect/) by Lawless English
[Modal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs) by Wikipedia
[Tense vs Aspect](https://collins.co.uk/blogs/collins-elt/tense-vs-aspect) by Collins
[Don't forget about voice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91122/how-many-tenses-are-there-in-english) by EL&U StackExchange
[Conclusion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91122/how-many-tenses-are-there-in-english) by EL&U StackExchange

Comment: Please edit, make the necessary attributions and add blockquotes because it looks like your words when it clearly isn't.

Comment: -1 lack of proper attribution